# Continuity of $A\colon X\to X^{*}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space. Consider $A\colon X\to X^{*}$. Take a sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ strongly convergent to some $x\in X$.

Does 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|(Ax_n-Ax,y)_{X^{*}\times X}|=0$$
for every $y\in X$ imply continuity of $A$? If so, why?

Comment: Is $A$ a linear map?

Comment: $A$ is affine and I managed to show that $A$ is bounded. What is more, $A$ is strongly monotone.

Comment: Affine means it differs from a linear map by a translation. Translations are homeomorphisms of topological vector spaces, so we can focus on the linear part. Yes, under these hypotheses $A$ is continuous. How did you show boundedness of $A$? (And boundedness in what sense? Do you know that a linear map between normed spaces is continuous if and only if it is [norm-]bounded?)

Comment: $$Ax=a(x,\cdot)-(L,\cdot)_{X^{*}\times X}+a(u,\cdot),$$ $a$ is bilinear map. So if I denote $l_{x}=a(x,\cdot)\in X^{*}$ I can  get the bound for $\|Ax\|$. I know that a linear map between normed spaces is continuous if and only if it is [norm-]bounded, but this time $A$ is affine and I wasn't sure.

Comment: $$\|Ax\|\le \|l_x\|_{X^{*}}+\|L\|_{X^{*}}+\|l_u\|_{X^{*}}$$ for all $x\in X$

Comment: So you just didn't know or temporarily forgot that an affine map is continuous if and only if the associated linear map is continuous. That's an occasionally useful fact.

Comment: You made me think about the boundedness of an operator $A:X\to X^{*}$. From the definition I should have the inequality $$\|Ax\|_{X^{*}}\le M \|x\|_{X}$$ for all $x\in X$ and for some $M\ge 0$. Can we deduce the boundedness (or maybe it is understood in that way) from $$|(Ax,y)_{X^{*}\times X}|\le M(x)\cdot \|y\| $$ for all $x,y \in X$ and $M(x)\ge 0$?

Comment: Note that $\lVert Ax\rVert_{X^{\ast}} \leqslant M\lVert x\rVert_X$ is only equivalent to boundedness for _linear_ operators, for a bounded nonlinear operator you usually don't have such an inequality. By Hahn-Banach, you have $\lvert (Ax,y)_{X^{\ast}\times X}\rvert \leqslant \lVert Ax\rVert\cdot \lVert y\rVert$, and you cannot do better. So whether you can deduce boundedness depends on what is known about $A$ and the function $M(x)$. For $M(x) = K\lVert x\rVert + C$, boundedness follows immediately.